# Using find to list files but not if inside a listed directory

Tags: bash, find

I've found a nice command which lists the files that do not belong to myUser:

```
find . ! -user myUser
```

The output looks like this:

```
A
A/AA.txt
B
B/BB
B/BB/BBB.txt
C/CC/CCC.txt
D
```

Where files have the .txt extension.

This is a little too redundant for what I want to do (apply a chown -R on those files).
I would like to use find as a starting point to end with a list like this:

```
A
B
C/CC/CCC.txt
D
```

In other words, I would like to find any entry (file/directory) not owned by myUser,
and which is not nested inside an already listed entry.

-maxdepth is not an option in this case, because I don't know for sure the organisation of the top level folder.

Comment: How is `C/CC/CCC.txt` a part of the expected outout? For one level, you could do: `find . -maxdepth 1 ! -user myUser`

Comment: @BlueMoon C/CC/CCC.txt would be part of the output if someone had applied a chown www-data:www-data on that particular file for instance, but not on any of the containing folders. In this case, using -maxdepth is not an option, I will update my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this command:

```
find . ! -user myUser -prune
```

- `-prune` True;  if  the  file  is  a directory, do not descend into it.